# OpenCV : Converting a float array into Mat

Tags: java, arrays, opencv

I am working on a **java** project where I have to convert a float array to opencv mat.
This is what I have done so far :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(floats));
Mat imgf = new Mat(2, 100, CvType.CV_32F);
imgf.put(2, 100, floats);
System.out.println(imgf.dump());
```

The variable `floats` return  this array(first line form the code):

```
[255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0, 127.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 127.5, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 127.5, 255.0, 127.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 127.5, 255.0, 127.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 127.5, 255.0, 127.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 127.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 255.0, 127.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.1125, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 251.8125, 60.5625, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 97.537506, 0.0, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 135.7875, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 168.9375, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 191.25, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 105.1875, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 191.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.1125, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

But I couldn't get that into the mat `imgf`.

The last line where I am trying to print the mat doesn't have a fixed result sometimes I get :

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And sometimes this :

```
[0, 6.7501031e-07, 6.6356984e-07, 9.3232773e-09, 1.4586571e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 6.7500696e-07, 6.6356984e-07, 9.3232773e-09, 1.4586571e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 6.7500696e-07, 6.6356984e-07, 5.8270483e-10, 1.0310071e-08, 2.5747301e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 6.7500696e-07, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 2.3308182e-09, 6.4900371e-07, 6.6356984e-07, 5.8270483e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 4.1653962e-11, 9.3232773e-09, 1.4586571e-19, 4.1653962e-11, 5.8270483e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.0621065e-05, 1.4586562e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 1.0621065e-05, 1.4586562e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 1.0310071e-08, 2.5747301e-12, 6.7500696e-07, 1.0310071e-08, 2.5747301e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 6.6356984e-07, 2.3308193e-09, 6.4900371e-07, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 9.3232728e-09, 1.4586571e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 6.6356984e-07, 9.3232773e-09, 1.4586571e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 6.7500696e-07, 6.6356984e-07, 2.3308193e-09, 6.4900371e-07, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 1.1708638e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12;
 1.458489e-19, 2.3308182e-09, 2.5783149e-09, 1.4586568e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 6.7500696e-07, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 9.3232728e-09, 1.4586571e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 6.7500696e-07, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 4.0292387e-11, 6.638179e-07, 6.6256933e-10, 1.0605886e-08, 9.3232773e-09, 1.4586571e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 4.166012e-11, 6.8247328e-07, 1.4586896e-19, 9.3232728e-09, 1.4586571e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 6.7500696e-07, 4.1240284e-08, 4.3673634e-05, 2.5182753e-12, 1.458489e-19, 9.3232728e-09, 1.4586571e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 6.6356984e-07, 2.3308193e-09, 0.00016614873, 2.5752289e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 6.6356984e-07, 2.3308193e-09, 1.0139325e-08, 5.8270483e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 6.7500696e-07, 6.6356984e-07, 9.3232773e-09, 1.4586571e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 6.7500696e-07, 6.6356984e-07, 9.3232773e-09, 1.4586571e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 6.7500696e-07, 6.6356984e-07, 2.3308193e-09, 2.5350566e-09, 2.57523e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 2.5751176e-12, 2.6948968e-09, 2.5749502e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 6.7500696e-07, 6.6356984e-07, 5.8270483e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 5.8270455e-10, 2.5028963e-12, 1.458489e-19, 2.5348863e-09, 4.8852866e-39]
```

I aim to return the same value as the float array , How can get that resolved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter you provide to the `imgf.put(2,100,floats)` is not correct.
You want to start from the very first Matrix element, so provide 0 for `row` and `col`

```
float floats[] = { 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, ... };
Mat imgf = new Mat(2, 100, CvType.CV_32F);
int row = 0, col = 0;
imgf.put( row, col, floats );
```

Comment: what a stupid mistake i made i should have read how put works

Comment: No worries. Beware though that the `put` [function](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html) expects different arguments when using 64bit float value